# Método para retornar string de um valor inteiro

Tags: python, funções

Tenho uma função `meses_dias` que receba um argumento, um número inteiro dias, e devolva uma string que diz quantas semanas e dias esse número representa. Por exemplo, `meses_dias(10)` deve devolver `1 semana(s) e 3 dias(s)`

---

Eu tentei isso :

```
def meses_dias(dias):
    return("{} meses(s) e {} dias(s).".format(dias//7))
```

Comment: Poderia melhorar o título da pergunta, né? O objetivo do título é justamente resumir o contexto da pergunta, mas o seu não faz isso. Além que no código que postou, sua *string* espera dois valores: a quantidade de semanas (que está como meses?) e o número excedente de dias (que não foi calculado).

Comment: sou novo no site amigo e não sei utiliza-lo ainda .

Comment: Escreva uma função chamada meses_dias que receba um argumento, um número inteiro diass, e devolva uma string que diz quantas semanas e dias esse número representa. Por exemplo, meses_dias(10) deve devolver, "1 semana(s) e 3 dias(s)."

Comment: o problema é exatamente esse que digitei acima.

Comment: @CleomirSantos bem-vindo ao site. Faça o tour e vai aprender como melhorar sua pergunta (editar, formatar, etc): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O principal problema no seu código é que a sua *string* espera dois valores, mas você está indicando apenas um. Você precisa calcular o número de semanas e o excedente de dias, que chega a completar uma semana. Você pode fazer isso com a divisão inteira e com o resto de divisão, ou alternativamente com a função [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod):

```
def meses_dias(dias):
    semanas, dias = divmod(dias, 7)
    return f"{semanas} semana(s) e {dias} dias(s)."

print(meses_dias(10)) # 1 semana(s) e 3 dias(s).
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/FlusteredFondExponent)</sup>

> **Nota:** `meses_dias` é um péssimo nome para uma função que calcula o número de semanas.

Comment: entendi , eu confundi realmente